# How can I display images with projection layouts in Orchard 1.7?

Tags: orchardcms

I use query layouts with properties and had been using .Url.Absolute in versions previous to 1.7 to get the path to an image.

Is there way to produce the image url and other properties from the new media library in a layout?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Bindings tab under Queries. Under Orchard.MediaLibrary.Models.MediaPartRecord you'll see MediaPath and FileName, that together should get you where you need to be: those properties will then be available for you to add from the layout editor. Ideally, you could bind the MediaUrl property, but I think it being read-only is what prevents it from showing in the possible bindings. That may be worth filing abug, because it would be a lot more convenient a solution.

Comment: I created the bindings as you described, but I do not understand where to go from there. I have an Media Library field "Image" that is attached to a content type "Artwork." How do I ask for the FileName (or other property) for that particular field?

Comment: Please file a bug, we are obviously missing dedicated tokens.

Answer (score 1):

for using `{Content.Fields.MyPicture.Url.Absolute}` you must Enable

> Url Alternates

from modules features first.

Comment: In this case what does MyPicture represent? I had to use `{Content.Fields.[contenttype].[imagefieldname].Url.Absolute}`

Comment: Sorry I meant I had to use `{Content.Fields.[contenttype].[imagefieldname].Url}`

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Url` token for `MediaLibraryPickerField` which is chainable with Url tokens.

Example:
`{Content.Fields.MyPicture.Url.Absolute}`

Comment: Is this in 1.7 or 1.7.1?  I am trying to use this URL in a shape template and can't find the right way to reference it.