# Orchard - show an Image from Media Library Picker Field

Tags: orchardcms

I created a new content definition, added a field "Media Library Picker Field" MYIMAGE.
There I can configure some things like "A content item is required" ... "Content Types and Parts" but I left them blank.

Then I can successfully select a image from my media library and see it from Admin/Contents/List.

Then I made a new query: I selected new layout, Html List, selected properties, add new property: "Title Part Title" with no configuration and MYIMAGE:Ids with no configuration.

Then I created a projection so I can see for every match of the query the titles BUT NO Ids.

I searched in shape tracing, i suppose I can find it in Zone[Content]->Content->List->PropertyWrapper (this is the first query result) and then under the Model Tab I suppose Model->Items->[0] should be the title so @Model.Items[1] should be the Ids.

How can I get the image's Id from @Model.Items[1]? And the URL?

Comment: i just asked the same question. i think there is a problem so that it's not working, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888031/how-can-i-display-images-with-projection-layouts-in-orchard-1-7

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved. See https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/19956.
There is also a module called Vitus.Utils that adds some very useful tokens for Media Library items. See http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Vitus.Utils/1.0