# Display image with Projection in Orchard 1.7

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

how to display image with with Projection in Orchard 1.7.

i have try but not able to get image its sow me ID with select html layout and custom display html.

can some on help me to get image with orchard projection/query

==Updated Post

I have one Query to select all company name (input text) , detail (input text) and company image, i want to show a list of all company name with image thumb on front site with projection and query ...list is coming but how to get image that is the problem.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ImagePart you should be able to access to MediaPart. MediaPart has FolderPath and FileName property. Just do something like this: Image.As.FolderPath to access to it in your shape.

If you are not using ImagePart, be more specific (e.g. showing some code)

Comment: thanks for reply @jmgomez ,i am new in orchard and mvc. do you any example for it.it would be great help for me..thanks

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you have a projections of ContentItems and those items have an ImagePart attached? Could you edit your post to show your ContentItem definition

Comment: see i have add what i want to do exactly with projection

Comment: So, you created the content from the dashboard, are you using a shape? If so, from your shape and for each ContentItem try to do: 
    ContentItem.Fields.CompanyImage.Url.Absolute 
Where ContentItem is each of your ContentItem projection.
I didn't try it before, I just saw the reply from Sebastian here:  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888031/how-can-i-display-images-with-projection-layouts-in-orchard-1-7) Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Put the code of your shape somewhere (question, gist, pastebin..) and also the name of the properties of your content item.